# count number of a specific string in entire data frame in Pandas and add its value in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 5 column data frame, I need to find how many times each element in first column(A) is repeated and add the amount in front of that element in a new column(F), for example 'a' in first Column(A) is repeated five times in entire data frame, so need to create column() and add 5 in related cell in row Zero and so on. appreciate to have your support. I am a newbie to python and need your precious comment.

below is the original data frame:

```
A   B   C   D   E
a   -            
b   a   -        
c   a   -        
d   b   a   -    
e   d   b   a   -
```

Preferred data frame would be:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
a   -               5
b   a   -           3
c   a   -           1
d   b   a   -       2
e   d   b   a   -   1
```

So far I have coded below lines but I could not make new column having the sum.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
 'B': {0: '-', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'd'}})

df['C'] = np.where(df['B'].isin(df['A'].values), df['B'], np.nan)
df['C'] = df['C'].map(dict(zip(df.A.values, df.B.values)))
df['D'] = np.where(df['C'].isin(df['B'].values), df['C'], np.nan)
df['D'] = df['D'].map(dict(zip(df.B.values, df['C'].values)))
df['E'] = np.where(df['D'].isin(df['C'].values), df['D'], np.nan)
df['E'] = df['E'].map(dict(zip(df['C'].values, df['D'].values)))

for cell in df['A']:
    print(cell)
    m=df.eq(cell).sum()
#   pd.DataFrame([m.values], columns=m.index)
    dep=sum(m)
    print(dep)
print(df)
```

and below is the out put of above codes:

a
5
b
3
c
1
d
2
e
1

```
A   B   C   D   E
a   -            
b   a   -        
c   a   -        
d   b   a   -    
e   d   b   a   -
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is it guaranteed by your data structure that column A only contains unique elements? If not, what should happen in this case?

Comment: Yes Column A only contains unique elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to create a mapping dictionary that contains unique elements in dataframe as its keys and their counts as values, then [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) this dictionary on column `A`:

```
from collections import Counter

df['F'] = df['A'].map(Counter(np.ravel(df)))
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  -           5
1  b  a  -        3
2  c  a  -        1
3  d  b  a  -     2
4  e  d  b  a  -  1
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks for your support it solved my issue. just one other question, how can I put C,D and E code lines for creating related columns in a loop to avoid repetition?

Comment: @Afshin IIUC, you want get counts for each column like `A, B, C, D, E`, right?

Comment: I am writing two lines to make Column C and repeat it for columns D&E, hence I have to write 6 lines, how can I put the two lines in for loop to avoid repetition?

Comment: @Afshin No problem, Can you update the question with the expected output?

Comment: Thank you so much Shubham, I will initiate a new question if I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['F'] = [np.count_nonzero(df.values == x) for x in df['A']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is another good solution for my problem